SQLAlchemy error creating relationship between tables
I'm trying to make a simple database using SQLAlchemy from two tables: Users and Couple.
The Couple table must contain a "couple" of users from the Users table.
For example:
Users:



id
user_name




1
user1


2
user2


3
user3


4
user4



Couple:



id
first_user_ldap
second_user_ldap




1
user1
user2


2
user3
user4



I tried to do this through “relationship” so that there was a one-to-many relationship, but it didn’t work.
I ask for your help.
Here is an example of my models:
class Couple(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'couples'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    first_user_ldap = relationship('Users', back_populates='Couple',
                                   lazy='dynamic')
    second_user_ldap = relationship('Users', back_populates='Couple',
                                    lazy='dynamic')


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_name = Column(String)



What didn't work? Please demonstrate the problem by including what actually went wrong.

sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Couple.first_user_ldap - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

This answer may address your problem given your multiple relationships from Couple to Users, but given that you may have omitted the underlying User.id for each of the respective user_ldap you may need to fill that in too.

I solved the problem.
one of the likely reasons was “dirty imports”, which... captured models from other files.
Now:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

Models:
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_name = Column(String)


class Couple(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'couples'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    first_user_ldap = Column(String, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    second_user_ldap = Column(String, ForeignKey('users.id'))

DataSet:
    db.insert(Users(id=1, user_name='user1'))
    db.insert(Users(id=2, user_name='user2'))
    db.insert(Users(id=3, user_name='user3'))
    db.insert(Users(id=4, user_name='user4'))
    db.insert(Users(id=5, user_name='user5'))
    db.insert(Users(id=6, user_name='user6'))
    db.insert(Couple(first_user_ldap=1, second_user_ldap=2))
    db.insert(Couple(first_user_ldap=3, second_user_ldap=4))
    db.insert(Couple(first_user_ldap=5, second_user_ldap=6))

